# Entering non-existent folders in Ubuntu (Apache)

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, php7

I have a Ubuntu server with Apache installed on it.
When I login to my site:

```
mysite.com/folder/index.php
```

It works as expected.

Then, by chance I discovered that I could enter:

```
mysite.com/folder/index.php/anythinghere
```

And get the same page (index.php)

Even though **index.php**  is not a folder, and I don't have any folder there with that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are note entering any "folder". You have some `RewriteRule`s in your apache configuration or in a .htaccess file that map al requests in `/folder` to that php file, regardless on what comes after it.

Comment: apache configuration by default
I haven't modified anything
and i dont use .htaccess